# Positive integers $a,b,$ and $c$ satisfy the equations. Find the value of $a+b+c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> **Question:** Positive integers $a,b,$ and $c$ satisfy the equations$$29^2-a^2=28^2-b^2=27^2-c^2$$If $a<20$, what is the value of $a+b+c$?

I first tried factoring the three equations so that$$(29-a)(29+a)=(28-b)(28+b)=(27-c)(27+c)$$But I don't really see a way to continue from there. I then looked at the difference of two squares and drew three right triangles of hypotenuse $29,28,27$ and a leg of length $a,b,c$ respectively.

The third side is then the square root of what we want, but I'm not sure what value still goes into $a$ and $b$ and $c$.

Any ideas on where I can begin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $a$ and $b$ first, we will have:

$a^2-b^2=29^2-28^2=57 \Rightarrow (a-b)(a+b)=57$

Because $57>0, a>0, b>0$, we will have $0<a-b<a+b<57$.

There are only two positive cases:

$57=1 \times 57= 3 \times 19$.

Because $a-b<a+b$, we will have two set of equations:

- Case one: ${\begin{cases}a-b=1\\a+b=57\end{cases}}\Leftrightarrow {\begin{cases}a=29\\b=28\end{cases}}$, this result is eliminated because $a<20$.
- Case two: ${\begin{cases}a-b=...\\a+b=...\end{cases}}\Leftrightarrow {\begin{cases}a=...\\b=...\end{cases}}$

With $a=...;b=...$, you can solve for $c$, but I won't give it away (or you can see the spoiler below).

> $a=11;b=8;c=3\Rightarrow a+b+c=11+8+3=22$

Comment: Edited because the OP only asks where they can begin, so I should only give the full solution as a spoiler

Comment: Normally, I'm bad at such problems. Can you tell me your thought process and why you took the first two equations instead of the last two?

Comment: That's what I've seen first when I look at this problem, so I choose $29^2-28^2=57=1×57=3×19$ immediately. However the last two also work: $28^2-27^2=55=1 \times 55= 5 \times 11$. Taking the first and the last is harder though, because you need to solve five cases instead of two for $29^2-27^2=112=1\times 112= 2\times 56=4 \times 28=8 \times 14= 16 \times 7$.